# Typescript interface operating over the same implementation exclusively

Tags: typescript, interface, this, implementation

I have a code where I'm doing some statistics over some variables. It basically is the same code but duplicated over and over so I've decided to provide a nice abstraction.

The problem is that those statistics are performed over value objects so I need to define an interface for those objects to allow for the abstraction.

My 2 current value objects are `Money` and `Time` and I want to be able to plug them into a class like the following (the abstracted code):

```
class Average<T extends Operable> {
   private value: T;
   private count: number;

   public constructor(init: T) {
      this.value = init;
      this.count = 0;
   }

   public add(value: T): void {
      this.value = this.value.add(value);
      this.count++;
   }

   public getAverage(): T {
      return this.value.divide(Math.max(1, this.count));
   }
}
```

For this, I need, of course, the `Operable` interface that `Money` and `Time` need to extend from so I went ahead and attempted to create it:

```
interface Operable {
   add(value: Operable): Operable;
   divide(value: number): Operable;
}
```

This, however, is not quite what I want because it would allow for `Money` and `Time` to be cross-operated (f.e. `const m = new Money(); const t = new Time(); m.add(t);`). In addition to this, my IDE rightfully complaints about this on `Average.add` method:

```
Type 'Operable' is not assignable to type 'T'.
     'Operable' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Operable'.
```

A few Google searches later I learnt that you can use `this` in an interface to refer to the instance type so I changed the interface as follows:

```
interface Operable {
   add(value: this): this;
   divide(value: number): this;
}
```

This clears the error in `Average.add` but pushes it to the value object's methods (here is an example for `Money.add`):

```
Property 'add' in type 'Money' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Operable'.
     Type '(money: Money) => Money' is not assignable to type '(value: this) => this'.
       Type 'Money' is not assignable to type 'this'.
         'Money' is assignable to the constraint of type 'this', but 'this' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Money'.
```

Is there a way to get this sort of construction working in Typescript? Many thanks!

Edit: please, note that my value objects are immutable so changing the `Average.add` method to just `this.value.add(value);` is not an option.

EDit2: Here are the definitions for `Money` and `Time`:

```
class Money {
   private readonly amount: number;
   private readonly currency: string;

   public constructor(amount: number, currency: string) {
      this.amount = amount;
      this.currency = currency;
   }

   public add(value: Money): Money {
      return new Money(this.amount + value.amount, this.currency);
   }

   public divide(value: number): Money {
      return new Money(this.amount / value, this.currency);
   }
}

class Time {
   private readonly duration: number;

   public constructor(duration: number) {
      this.duration = duration;
   }

   public add(value: Time): Time {
      return new Time(this.duration + value.duration);
   }

   public divide(value: number): Time {
      return new Time(this.duration / value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where are your `Money` and `Time` definitions? Could you [edit] to make sure this is a  [mre] so that when you say the error is "pushed to the value object's methods" it's something we can all look at in our IDEs?

Comment: (please see prev comment).  Like, maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/N92xqm) is what you're looking for, but I had to make guesses about `Money` and `Time` that might turn out to be inappropriate.  Let me know how to proceed here.

Comment: Hi @jcalz, thanks for your reply. And yes, you guessed correctly their implementations. Isn't there any other way to do it without using generic interfaces? Don't get me wrong, it works great but having to provide a type argument feels like a hack when you want to reference whatever class is implementing the interface. Nevertheless, this unblocks my work so, many thanks :-)

Comment: "Isn't there any other way to do it"?  Nothing I can think of that isn't worse.  You could feel free to use `this` types and type assertions, but the compiler will complain because if someone subclasses `Money` or `Time`, then the subclasses would inherit incorrect `add()` and `divide()` methods. I will mention this in my answer. As for "feels like a hack", this is the standard way that Java does things all the time, and indeed the `this` type is implement that way behind the scenes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for so-called [*F-bounded quantification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification), also known as *recursive [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)*.  You want an `Operable` implementation to only deal with "itself".

You found the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), which is a form of recursive constraint, and is quite close to what you want; callers would indeed be restricted so that `money.add(time)` and `time.add(money)` would fail (unless `time` and `money` happen to be structurally compatible, which they're not).  But *implementations* are similarly restricted, and `this` doesn't mean "the class on which this method is declared", it means "the type of the current `this` context, including possible subclasses."  So the reason this fails:

```
class BadTime {
    constructor(private readonly duration: number) { }
    add(value: this): this {
        return new BadTime(this.duration + value.duration); // error
    }
}
```

is because the compiler cannot prevent you from doing this:

```
class ReallyBadTime extends BadTime {
    hello() { console.log("hi") };
}
const rbt = new ReallyBadTime(10).add(new ReallyBadTime(20));
//    ^? const rbt: ReallyBadTime
rbt.hello(); // RUNTIME ERROR
```

Inside `ReallyBadTime`, `this` is required to have a `hello()` method, and so the `add()` method must return something with a `hello()` method.  But the implementation of `add()` inherited from `BadTime` doesn't do this.  The runtime error at `rbt.hello()` is what the compiler error inside the `add()` implementation is warning you about.

---

Anyway, if you want to be able to implement `add()` and `divide()` so that subclasses don't pretend to do things they can't do, you'll need to change `this` to a more general recursive constraint.  Here's one way to do it:

```
interface Operable<T extends Operable<T>> {
    add(value: T): T;
    divide(value: number): T;
}
```

The constraint `T extends Operable<T>` expresses the "itself" restriction.  That part is essentially the same as how the polymorphic `this` type works under the covers.  The difference is that the type *argument* for `this` automatically narrows to whatever the calling object type is (e.g., `ReallyBadTime`), while `Operable<Time>` will always have `Time` as `T` even in subclasses.

Then you just have to propagate the constraint to `Average`:

```
class Average<T extends Operable<T>> {
  // ✂ snip ⋯ snip ✂ //
}
```

and you're pretty much done.  If you want, you can use [an `implements` clause](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses) on `Money` and `Time` to make sure you've implemented it correctly:

```
class Money implements Operable<Money> {
  // ✂ snip ⋯ snip ✂ //
}

class Time implements Operable<Time> {
  // ✂ snip ⋯ snip ✂ //
}
```

but this is completely optional. An `implements` clause doesn't affect the types; all it does is warn you inside the class if you've made a mistake.  You can get by just fine without it (but any mistake you make will only be noticed when you try to *use* an improperly implemented `Money` or `Time` as an argument to `new Average()`):

```
class Money {
  // ✂ snip ⋯ snip ✂ //
}

class Time {
  // ✂ snip ⋯ snip ✂ //
}
```

---

Okay, let's make sure it works:

```
const moneyAverage = new Average(new Money(10, "USD"));
moneyAverage.add(new Money(20, "GBP"));
moneyAverage.add(new Money(30, "EUR"));
const m = moneyAverage.getAverage();
console.log(m.toString()); // 30.00 USD // hmm, might not be right

const timeAverage = new Average(new Time(10));
timeAverage.add(new Time(20));
timeAverage.add(new Time(30));
const t = timeAverage.getAverage();
console.log(t.toString()) // 30 shakes of a lamb's tail // also not sure
  
timeAverage.add(new Money(40, "USD")); // error
// -----------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'Money' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Time'.

const foo = { add() { return 1 }, divide() { return 2 } };
new Average(foo); // error!
// -------> ~~~
// Argument of type '{ add(): number; divide(): number; }' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'Operable<{ add(): number; divide(): number; }>'.
```

Looks good.  Aside from the weirdness of currencies and time units, code that's supposed to compile does compiler.  And when you make mistakes, like mixing `time` and `money`, or when you call `new Average()` on something that isn't a valid `Operable`, you get informative errors about them.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBuBTATmA5ogPAFWogHgC6IB2AJjAPIAOKYARiFtgHwvQDeAUNL9NcgCW8MMWgiQAV0QAuaNgDcPPgOGjE0YAHtJJQnJKSAtvRRLlvapMaDgmrSQiFkk4IS3IAFIJKD98gEpOCz5eQgALQQgAOglpaABeaB8-JVDQiKjo7V1CROgABjS+AF8uEKsbOzAyMk842UC5eC1BMmD0vkyYhvzu2LApRGiauoaA4s7+nL0AalnJ6DKK6xBbaAxCBDoMTwC5XG5O3mREQklkEmh+huiyYTbETwBZUXDoozB8TwBGABprpEYjNCAEJiEyssuD5iMgAGZgYAaGh0RjMPBEUgUaAo1BonBsDp8Ub1QbSA77eSLe7wR6koYGYymZCUxRcZagSAwZ4ORAATyJliEIjEpxqDhAArARh0ekZJjMFWF6mgYrIEoFwAupxIwD5cicQhIaHMoUqazs2kczlc7i80tl-kMCuQAK1yB1eoNzh8aCCR2O-QduXywb0iwyQOy2tIevy7s9fMWyzNq3WJIach5JH5lOz-MF6VO50u0BzAHdoPm+Z4gzKQ7NxGThmHCADpjHdXzwaEUyo03YaXTM2WmSg87yBQHOsWLlcK1XJ7Wo63oAB6JtDdtRhOx7vJ8oZLQAZR9xr2hdCs9Ldcd0XcADFBPhEHUAExBRsAImgP8bHY9PcIXKZZnCnEJOSgaAACEamwQQjA0ad0itQ1bQ8TxVBFDQ1Q1aAyAuURBAceVmX9JYQlCDNmzkbpKW6S9jmvedEErWCyHgxDlyyAjUEIYirkbW5eKIhwJnXDcUGQDxKNKYDQkgmAACVEEGSV2M4jQCGIcgYA0hCkNk3hwkQEAQC0C8OHsRwtCYaJzLQTwv0iL8ghKA8FIcJxVXoPIkgXFS1L5fSuJ+AoAhGWpPAC1SzOCuCDM8N9wp7Pg1w3PgAD0AH5rO85BfLkQK4pCxAQgKwhohMsyLPE9LoCUgBVAA5bAAElngAUWgTqlKUyglPZTRRGAcJoE8RB-QgrzbOGByJqCeqKqq0zzOSGASC0PIwGgOFdDcAT2S4RT5AMwssJVXCSElfDCP4kjRxdU1+yqPKbTcDCRPukhSPHRiwijL6BPyIGHAPFZXuohlTsQ1kzuQq8zjnMtWJhp5+lBwTN2kO47oE1LeD7SwB3wh4yCeEdnTIg54aM1UkdLBdNO4mJMfXbHJvBo9TyNRypuOemSyuDG8YcaBv2gCBwjAABrRAYC0OFoB28ATAAchgQgwEEEAv2AspULyGUcz5bZUAwfIFzN9AngXatfgKAEv0a48ABFXPBY3+WtjBIrqO2l2Sp2AHFoIABQ9pQvdNpBzZbKKA5NzwAGZHd-TrGqUyPjq8o38mjn3hk2Qu9iUVDZvsrRHKMe8TzPPm6o3VPogKApoBd12JOgcIjCMAEjEENBwjyTa8lMVVB+H8pDeuAzC8t1GS6ZxKwrBJR+MQwu-ei1HmeSteuA3xAt5JZeuNTg+Z782fN9jm3omLu-dnBcu7Pmyr3B5309kWpu26l2W8toCK2VtAVW9ANbXG1iALugwIBaDLFtSWFwyrlCPifBOqN7YABY07OzdpHLuUkZL1QALTkIoZQ0h7AAB+dD6EMMYYwrg9VYDIDQMYUgeQQGED5LQaAatqxq3Wog7aUBB4kAYEwa4CDqBgFQIhWEwCla8P4WrTSatojT1zrtLQCCkhWRJORZi0AfhLABEOcmllBbIzfEsJYSgrZPyeHCPRjc8Aeg8AAQhYRuKh5DaF0N8XAdhnC9DKOuHwjQatDFRUpFTMwpNaRWPiWOZACgljCKiKI5W4i0CSLRDI6AwS5EKLOCgCJqjom4ikVgWJdRUlPSSXSRpzIMklBYJorgQA)

Comment: Oh, wow! Many thanks for this super detailed explanation. Now it makes totally sense why the type argument is needed. I definitely learnt something new. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change your operable type to:

```
type Operable = {
   add<T extends Operable>(value: T): T;
   divide<T extends Operable>(value: number): T;
}
```

[Here's a working sample](https://tsplay.dev/WozyPm)

Comment: Hi @Meir. Many thanks for your reply. It does indeed work but it does not offer the strict typing I'm looking for (i.e. you could make the `add` and `divide` methods to operate on different value objects as long as they where Operable). I guess the solution to this problem would be to push the type argument to the Operable type itself (f.e. `type Operable<T extends Operable<T>> = ...`). This solution, however, would not be that different from jcalz's one. Many thanks for sharing it tho!